# htaccess redirecting url but keeping typed url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have managed to use .htaccess to redirect the domain url to a page within the site.  Actually, I didn't learn any of it, I just used a web form from the server.

Anyway, it only achieves the effect of redirecting and shows the newly redirected URL, whereas I want it to remain as the one typed in.

Yes this surely is a common question, but I tried following the advice of another post on this site regarding this (removing some flags) and it didn't help.

Here's my .htaccess file right now (more-or-less):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.a-site.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.a-site.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.a-site.com/a-file.html [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditions seem extraneous:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a-site.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.a-site.com$
```

Which could also be written as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?a-site.com$
```

Looks like it's the same host match done twice. But your `RewriteRule` will always redirect the browser because it has a `http://www.a-site.com` in front, which tells apache to redirect with a 302. Try removing it:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /a-file.html [L]
```

Comment: Thank you.  This didn't seem to make any difference, though.  Oh and despite what I wrote, the first RewriteCond was actually for a-site.com (without the www) so they were different.

Comment: Hi, it did work, I think my browser was somehow caching the old url.  Switching to a different profile in firefox got the desired effect.

Comment: @RobF Weird, stuff like this usually takes affect immediately. I've edited the answer to fix the condition typo